# Ubuntu One android Contacts app -- last sync failed

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, contacts

On my HTC Desire I pressed "sync all" and at about the 77th contact it just said "last sync failed".

Why did it fail? What could the problem be? Thanks.

Comment: According to [this official page](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/why-is-contacts-sync-no-longer-active/) here, mobile contacts syncing is no longer actively supported on mobile versions as of June, 2011. So, this question has now become obsolete and hence I vote to close it off.